# How do disable windows 10 notifcations during VLC playback

Tags: windows-10, vlc-media-player, notifications

When I'm watching a movie in VLC, it is incredibly annoying to have the immersive experience ruined by a windows 10 pop up notification. Is there some way to prevent windows 10 notifications while VLC is playing, but have them fully enabled when it isn't?

Windows 10 version: 10.0.17134. Home edition

I have configured focus assist. But what I really want is for focus assist to automatically turn on when I'm in VLC and automatically turn off once I've finished with VLC. If I have to manually enable it and disable it I'm just going to forget

Comment: Have you tried configuring Focus Assist?

Answer (score 0):

I found right clicking on focus assist and selecting **Go To Settings** then make sure "**When I am using apps in full screen mode**" is turned on does well for me.

However alarms by nature will still go off and send a notification. Otherwise they are useless to set.